# NGXS @Select usage with state model

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

When using an NGXS `@Select` decorator what is the right way to access properties defined on the state model.

E.g with the following state defined:

```
export interface UserStateModel {
 firstname: string;
 lastname: string;
}

@State<UserStateModel>({
  name: 'user',
  defaults: {}
})
export class UserState {..}
```

In a component if I want to select the user state like this:

```
..export class MyComponent {

  @Select(UserState) user$: Observable<UserState>;

   ngOnInit(){
     this.user$.subscribe(u => {
         //do something with user state
         console.log(u.firstname);
     });
   }   
}
```

I get typescript errors as the `firstname` property doesn't exist on `UserState` (as it's defined on the related model type). If I'm referencing the property in the component html template then I don't have any issue.

There is a [related discussion](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/160) around selector usage but I just want to confirm what I should expect with the current version (and if I'm doing this correctly!).

I'm using `"@ngxs/store": "^3.0.0-rc.2",`

Comment: I am now wondering if the right way is to declare my selector as `@Select(UserState) user$: Observable<UserStateModel>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The observable decorated by the `@Select` decorator will be of the model's data type and not the state class. ie:

```
export class MyComponent {

  @Select(UserState) user$: Observable<UserStateModel>;

   ngOnInit(){
     this.user$.subscribe(u => {
         //do something with user state
         console.log(u.firstname);
     });
   }   
}
```

Another note is that I recommend the use of the async pipe in your template so that Angular manages the subscription and unsubscription for you.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for confirming that from my earlier comment.
Re: async pipe, yes have been using that where possible. I'm trying out NGXS on an existing Angular app, so using the pipe in component templates, but I have some services that are subscribers, so I think I need to subscribe manually there (no template).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [runnable demo project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-books-selector?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) I just created.

It provides a demo to select `allBooks$` and `thickBooks$` from a `BookStateModel` that contains `books: Book[]`.

Things to note:

- `@Selector()` is declared ([memoized](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#memoized-selectors)) in `BookState.ts` so that it can be used elsewhere.
- These memoized selectors can be used via `@Select(Xxx)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that demo link!

Comment: Invaluable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment on your question is the correct way to select a whole state container.

An alternative (and in my opinion better solution) is using [a root-state model to infer types in Selectors.](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/160#issuecomment-521216207) 
With those you can select only the necessary state attributes and still have type-safety.

My thoughts on the currently posted solutions:

- **Memoized Selectors**: That is a lot of overhead to write a memoized selector for every unmodified state attribute you would want to select. I'd also expect that there's a small performance drawback for memoized selectors, that's probably also the reason why it is not an official solution for the [types issue.](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/160)
- **Selecting the whole state**: Super inconvenient since you'd rarely need a whole state (e.g. in your example, select only the firstname of your UserState). Most of the time you'd want to select a specific state attribute and bind that into your view or subscribe to it. You'll gain less overhead and clearer / cleaner code.